# Как на Си ввести массив чисел до перехода на новую строку

Tags: c

Числа вводятся через пробел. Как сделать так, чтобы ввод завершился при нажатии энтера?
Пишу `while (scanf("%d", c[j]) ==1)`, но идет бесконечно.

Comment: Один из вариантов - ввести строку через `getline()`, а потом уже её разбирать на числа.

Comment: покажите минимальный код. Очень интересно какого типа у вас переменная `c`.

Comment: int c[40] задал

Comment: сначала аргумент поменяйте на указатель `scanf("%d",` **&** `c[j])` ; потом уже будет зависать, и ждать числа.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна функция `skip_spaces`, которая пропускает пробельные символы из входного потока. Если встретился перевод строки, она возвращает ложь. Пример использования ниже:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool skip_spaces() {
    for (; ; ) {
        int c = getc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!isspace(c)) {
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            return true;
        }
        if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    const int n = 40;
    int a[n];
    int j = 0;
    while (j < n && skip_spaces() && scanf("%d", &a[j]) == 1) {
        ++j;
    }
    printf("====\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < j; ++i) {
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, a[i]);
    }
    printf("====\n");
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror temp.c
>
> $ ./a.out
>  1  2   3   
> ====
> 0: 1
> 1: 2
> 2: 3
> ====
> ```

**P.S.** `skip_spaces` не забирает из входного потока найденный перевод строки. Если вы переделаете этот пример для чтения из нескольких строк, то обнаружите, что дальше первой строки чтение не идёт. Напишите сами функцию `skip_eol` по аналогии чтобы решить эту проблему.